# How to type non ascii characters in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, console

English is not my native language. When I type non ascii characters in Rails console (in Bash) it shows question mark in place of every non ascii character.

[image]

Currently I have this configuration in my bashrc file:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_ALL
```

Still it shows question mark instead of non ascii character. this problem occurred after I switched to macOS High Sierra. My server is Ubuntu 16.04 with bash.